# base64 result giving black image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, base64

This is code for get image from video by canvas but when I save this base64 code into image, I get a black image.

What is the reason?

My javascript is

```
var input = document.getElementById('file1');
input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = url;
    var snapshot = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var img_data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ImageUpload.php",
            data: 'imgBase64=' + img_data,
            success: function(data) {
                -- -
            }
        });
        video.removeEventListener('canplay', snapshot);
    };
    video.addEventListener('canplay', snapshot);
});
```

and this is PHP code

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['imgBase64'];
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
mkdir("uploads/");
file_put_contents("uploads/".time().'.png', $data);
?>
```

Comment: I notice, everywhere in the javascript you refer to `image/jpg` ... then you save it as `.png` ... I wonder if it could be as simple as the file extension

Comment: try this `data:{'imgBase64':img_data},`

Comment: i replace my code with this <code>data:{'imgBase64':img_data}</code> but again same proble i got image black

Comment: @Bravo that's not JSON.  It's a key/value pair which is how you normally pass `data`.  Using `data: 'imgBase64=..` means OP is passing a single unnamed string in the POST data, but then trying to read it with `$_POST['imgBase64']` - OP is not passing an `imgBase64` parameter, so this is empty (as I understand how php `$_POST` works, which, tbh, is limited)

Comment: @freedomn-m my bad ... byt `data: 'imgBase64=' + img_data,` would be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` wouldn't it? perhaps the mime type needs to be set in the request

Comment: I'm guessing the "blank" image because it's all 0s - so will be one of:  putting the data on the canvas / getting the data from the canvas / sending the data / receiving the data / saving it to file / reading it from file.   Would help substantially if OP did some debugging to determine which it is.

Comment: Used OPs code, every video selected gives the same base64 encode (a blank image) - so we're all looking at the ajax/php and it's the canvas render that's the issue (or at least... first issue).   Nice of OP to narrow it down for us... https://jsfiddle.net/crbv7ezd/

Comment: thanks everyone i solved my problem @Bravo

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome (at least), you can only get a snapshot from the video once it starts playing.

If you add `autoplay` to your video, then immediately `pause()` it, you can get a snapshot.

```
var input = document.getElementById('file1');
input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var video = document.createElement('video');

    // autoplay video
    video.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
    video.src = url;

    // immediately stop the autoplay
    video.pause();


    var snapshot = function() {
       ...
       // no change
    };
    video.addEventListener('canplay', snapshot);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crbv7ezd/1/